# Changing the entire string in a string builder object

Tags: c#, string, stringbuilder

I have the following code:

```
using System;
using System.Text;

public class Program
{
    private static StringBuilder mystrb = new StringBuilder("hello");
    public static void Main()
    {
        mystrb.Clear();
        mystrb.Append("chau");
    }
}
```

is there any other way of entirly replacing the string in the string builder, i am looking for a one sentence way of doing it if it exist.

Comment: What's wrong with clearing it with `.Clear();`? - one line as requested `mystrb.Clear().Append("chau");`

Comment: also a way of doing it :)

Comment: one sentence = one line?

Comment: What about just not creating it in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best option is not to instantiate with a default at all. Since you are immediately replacing it with something else, just leave it empty (`new StringBuilder()`) or null.

```
private static StringBuilder mystrb;
```

If you have oversimplified your sample code, then just create a new instance:

```
mystrb = new StringBuilder("chau");
```

Comment: Then just create a new instance.

Answer (score 3):

What's wrong with just re-constructing the StringBuilder? The old one will just be garbage collected.

```
mystrb = new StringBuilder("chau");
```

Answer (score 0):

I think Ian's solution of simply overwriting your object with a new one is the best solution, but if for some reason you don't like that then you could do something like this:

```
static void StringBuilderReplaceText(StringBuilder sb, string newText)
{
    sb.Clear();
    sb.AppendLine(newText);
}
```

I was initially going to simply inherit from the `StringBuilder` object and add a new `Replace` extension method but apparently the object is [sealed](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/88c54tsw(v=vs.120).aspx) for some reason.

So yea, technically this would allow you to replace the content of a `StringBuilder` with a single line by later using `StringBuilderReplaceText(myStringBuilder, "my new text");` but I really don't see why you'd do this instead of just re-using the constructor.